# pandoc-ruby error when running documented example

Tags: ruby, pandoc

When running the following script using pandoc-ruby (directly from the documentation) I get an error.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pandoc-ruby'
puts PandocRuby.convert('# Markdown Title', :from => :markdown, :to => :html)
```

Output:

```
[dan@FIOS-RH test-markdown]$ ruby convert.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:250:in `format_flag': undefined method `length' for :from:Symbol (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:241:in `create_option'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:225:in `prepare_options'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `inject'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:222:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:222:in `inject'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:222:in `prepare_options'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:227:in `prepare_options'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `inject'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:222:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:222:in `inject'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:222:in `prepare_options'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:131:in `convert'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pandoc-ruby-0.7.4/lib/pandoc-ruby.rb:86:in `convert'
    from convert.rb:3

[dan ]$ pandoc --version
pandoc 1.11.1
...

[dan ]$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

pandoc-ruby version: 0.7.4
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The error is at line#4,show that line please..

Comment: Apologies - that was a typo (error was from a version with a blank line) now edited with the actual error code.

Comment: Is this created by you? https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby/issues/9

Comment: Yes it is (thought it might get more attention here)

Comment: Okay.. :) can you upgrade the Ruby to 1.9+ ? probably they used inside their code `Symbol#length` which is not available in Ruby version you are using..

Comment: please update me with your result.. :) curious to know that..

Comment: After trying a failing for a while to upgrade ruby, I'm giving up, so I'm unable to confirm this fix. If I gain the strength to tackle this in the future I'll let you know the outcome